# Docky Bookmarks AND Mounted Drives Plugins won't work

Tags: docky

I recently installed KDE in Ubuntu, and to my surprise, Docky works in KDE (dunno really). After two minutes of testing, I realized that I wanted GNOME more, so I decided to uninstall KDE Desktop. Before uninstalling, I tried to make Nautilus the default file manager in KDE, clicking apply and everything After getting back to pure gnome...

Docky won't open my bookmarks, except the Computer Icon... The bookmarks were the ones in the sidebar.

How can I fix it so that I can use my bookmarks in GNOME again?

PS: I tried dragging and dropping the bookmarks (which are viewable in Places menu) to the Dock and clicking it won't open it.

I tried running it from the terminal and after clicking a bookmark, here's this error:

```
[Error 12:04:04.979] [SystemService] Error opening files. The application doesn't support files/URIs or wasn't found.
```

Runing it from docky --debug

```
[Info  09:48:12.145] Docky version: 2.0.7 Release
[Info  09:48:12.249] Kernel version: 2.6.35.22
[Info  09:48:12.250] CLR version: 2.0.50727.1433
[Debug 09:48:15.171] [UserArgs] BufferTime = 0
[Debug 09:48:15.171] [UserArgs] MaxSize = 2147483647
[Debug 09:48:15.171] [UserArgs] NetbookMode = False
[Debug 09:48:15.171] [UserArgs] NoPollCursor = False
[Debug 09:48:16.057] [PluginManager] Plugin manager initialized.
[Info  09:48:16.190] [DockController] Setting theme: Smoke
[Info  09:48:17.677] [PluginManager] Loaded "Docky.Widgets,1.0".
[Info  09:48:17.685] [PluginManager] Loaded "Docky.Widgets,1.0".
[Info  09:48:17.685] [PluginManager] Loaded "Clock".
[Info  09:48:17.712] [PluginManager] Loaded "Trash".
[Info  09:48:17.873] [PluginManager] Loaded "Battery Monitor".
[Debug 09:48:17.943] [BatteryMonitorProcItem] Hiding battery item (capacity=0) max_capacity=-1) (OnBattery=False)
[Info  09:48:17.999] [PluginManager] Loaded "Mounter".
[Debug 09:48:18.238] [MountProvider] Adding 116 GB Filesystem.
[Info  09:48:18.241] [PluginManager] Loaded "Bookmarks".
[Debug 09:48:18.247] [BookmarksItemProvider] Updating bookmarks.
[Info  09:48:18.531] [PluginManager] Loaded "CPU Monitor".
[Info  09:48:19.412] [Helper] Starting banshee_control.py
[Info  09:48:19.693] [Helper] Starting deluge_badge.py
[Info  09:48:19.700] [Helper] Starting gajim_badge.py
[Info  09:48:19.716] [Helper] Starting liferea_badge.py
[Info  09:48:19.738] [Helper] Starting pidgin_control.py
[Info  09:48:19.778] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/docky/helpers/banshee_control.py
[Info  09:48:19.779] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/docky/helpers/deluge_badge.py
[Info  09:48:19.779] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/docky/helpers/gajim_badge.py
[Info  09:48:19.779] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/docky/helpers/gtg_menus.py
[Info  09:48:19.779] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/docky/helpers/liferea_badge.py
[Info  09:48:19.779] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/docky/helpers/open_terminal_here.py
[Info  09:48:19.779] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/docky/helpers/pidgin_control.py
[Info  09:48:19.779] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/docky/helpers/rhythmbox_control.py
[Info  09:48:19.779] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/docky/helpers/tomboy_menus.py
[Info  09:48:19.779] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/docky/helpers/zeitgeist_docky.py
[Info  09:48:19.779] [HelperService] Helper added: /usr/share/docky/helpers/zeitgeist_journal.py
[Info  09:48:20.376] [DrawingService] Could not find 'gajim', using fallback of 'extension'.
[Info  09:48:22.865] [Helper] deluge_badge.py :: No module named deluge.ui.client
[Info  09:48:22.892] [Helper] deluge_badge.py has exited (Code 0).
[Error 09:48:33.678] [SystemService] Error opening files. The application doesn't support files/URIs or wasn't found.
```

Comment: I tried dragging and dropping the bookmarks from Places, but clicking then won't open it

Comment: ????can you rewrite the question in a clearer way

Comment: edited it a little.

Comment: Can you take the things you've tried in the comments and update your question? That way we have everything in one place. Please see the FAQ: http://askubuntu.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this worked for me:

1. Kill Docky (`killall docky`)
2. Open nautilus (or whatever file browser you use)
3. Right-click a folder
4. Select "Open with Other Application..."
5. Make sure "Remember this application for 'folder' files" is checked
6. Click Open
7. Restart Docky

I was getting a file-not-found error. It took me a bit, but I realized that it was trying to open the folders with Rythmbox. Mine might just be a really strange situation, but I'd say it's worth a shot just in case.

Comment: I think it's because I had Rythmbox pinned to the dock when I dragged my folder, and accidentally dragged it into Rythmbox. That area is sort of tricky to hit, so I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if it has happened to some of you with other applications.

Comment: This anwered it. THANKS! NOW, Dropping DockbarX...

Answer (score 1):

`killall docky`, then go to `~/.conf/gtk-3.0/` copy bookmarks to `~`. Rename it to `.gtk-bookmarks`
Start `docky` with bookmarks showing and working.

```
killall docky
cp ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks ~/.gtk-bookmarks
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything in the Docky settings to specify how bookmarks are managed.  Have you tried a purge of docky and a reinstall of the package.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge docky
sudo apt-get clean docky

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docky
```

If that fails, open gconf-editor and browse to:

`/apps/docky-2/Docky/Interface/DockPreferences/Dock1`

The launchers key shows what shortcuts are run for each launcher.  Pick one that isn't working and post the contents on here.  It may be the launchers are corrupted somehow.

Comment: tried it in four commands, the bookmarks still won't work

Comment: Run Docky with --debug and post what you get when clicking a bookmark.

Comment: same error. [SystemService] Error opening files. The application doesn't support files/URIs or wasn't found.

Comment: added more detail

Comment: The Launchers displays apps for Xiphos, Cheese, Banshee, Terminal, Chromium, Empathy, and GVBAM. I checked the plugins, the bookmark items are there. I also checked my sortlist: does the bookmarks put the launchers like "file://Bookmark path" where "Bookmark path" is the absolute filepath of the bookmark (like when bookmarking folder X in your user folder, it uses /home/user/X)

Comment: yes, by looking in gconf you can see the path to the shortcut and then you are able to open the shortcut in vi and see what it says, post that contents if you can.

Comment: vi? open the shortcut in vi?? how??? :P

Comment: here, I pinned my home folder. file:///home/rekenber. it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error messages if you launch docky from the terminal?

killall docky && docky

then try your bookmarks.

Hope this helps,
Bodsda

Comment: Here is the error code :P [Error 12:04:04.979] [SystemService] Error opening files. The application doesn't support files/URIs or wasn't found.

Comment: Can you post the few lines above.  We need to know the application it is trying to use.

Comment: From reading the source it seems that the bookmarks aren't specifying a handler, so Docky is trying and failing to guess which one to use.  What happens if you create a new Launcher?

Comment: When I create a new laucher, example, pinning Cheese to dock, it works. if I pin File Browser (nautilus), it won't open. Opening a pinned item from the Places menu won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with docky per se. It is a problem with the file manager. Try deleting ~/.local/share/mime/mime.cache and logging out. Log in again, and now your bookmarks *should* work.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't worked. If there's only a way to do a "super fresh reinstallation" of docky... Oh, bookmarks opened in nautilus-elementary opens and works.